# ASP.NET C# how to Ignore certain styling in MasterPage

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

So I created a master page which serves as the Header and Footer template for every other template, the problem however, in one of the form, I put all the HTML that I wanted, CSS and JS when I load it theres some problem with the result. I figure out the problem is caused by this code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

If I remove that code, then the output will be what I want, the problem is that I dont want to remove that code in the MasterPage, is there a way to set that the Web form that follow that masterPage will ignore the

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Thanks and have a great day

Comment: have you included your form tag above your ContentPlaceHolder? i mean ContentPlaceHolder  is inside your form tag?

Comment: Hi
In the other Web Form that includes the MasterPage, theres no <Form> because it is inherited from the MasterPage, I needed the Web Form to avoid or ignore that <Form> from MasterPage

Comment: if there are no form tag on other forms it would've been fine, what is the error you are getting when there is the form tag? also can you put the entire code of your masterpage here on your question? might light things more clearly

Comment: Yeah, however tho if I remove the form in the masterPage it will solve the problem. However I don't want to remove it because other form need it

Comment: Alright, include your masterpage code here, also tell me what is your error that you are getting while there is form tag in your masterpage

Comment: Will upload soon, sorry.

Comment: Theres no error, it runs perfectly just the styling css  is off

Comment: alright so there is something wrong with your styling i need to see your codes then :)